# GPS - What am I seeing.?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I have an android application which makes use of GPS for tracking. This application is running in an android device installed in a cab so that I can track the cab. I have logging enabled on the application . Recently I observed a weird case while tracking the cab. At one point GPS was giving one location and after 80 seconds it gave a location which is several kilometers away from the first location. Surprisingly in both the cases the accuracy is < 20 (meters) which is the check I put to consider the location for tracking. Please find the logs I collected from the device.

```
----some logs
26 Dec,05:55:01.645 PM; GPS Fix state = true; NetworkLocation = Fri Dec 26 17:54:02 GMT+05:30 2014 17.805544,83.352301 Accuracy 3139.0; GPS Location = Fri Dec 26 17:54:58 GMT+05:30 2014 17.805017,83.35345 Accuracy 8.0;
----some logs
26 Dec,05:56:34.705 PM; GPS Fix state = true; NetworkLocation = Fri Dec 26 17:55:35 GMT+05:30 2014 17.81825,83.352313 Accuracy 3048.0; GPS Location = Fri Dec 26 17:56:09 GMT+05:30 2014 16.570113,82.055219 Accuracy 14.0;
----some logs
```

As you can see the network is still pointing somewhere around the initial location where as the GPS is pointing to some location which is far from the first location and still have the accuracy 14.!

The javadoc of Location class of android says -

```
 * We define accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence. In other
 * words, if you draw a circle centered at this location's
 * latitude and longitude, and with a radius equal to the accuracy,
 * then there is a 68% probability that the true location is inside
 * the circle.
```

Does that mean, the accuracy I got in the second trace fall in the other 32% and may be wrong.? I wonder if there is any reliable way to decide whether or not to consider a gps location instead of putting a check on accuracy.?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the GPS fix is back in the location of the cab after 40 mins. You can see that here.

```
26 Dec,06:35:21.851 PM; GPS Fix state = true; NetworkLocation = Fri Dec 26 18:35:20 GMT+05:30 2014 17.800334,83.352941 Accuracy 2887.0 GPS Location = Fri Dec 26 18:35:22 GMT+05:30 2014 17.799875,83.351936 Accuracy 14.0;
```

UPDATE: Today I went through the logs of all several devices in which this application is running and I observed this wrong GPS location with good accuracy value in multiple devices. All the devices are of same make and are using sim cards of same network provider.

Comment: The cabbie hacked it to cover up picking his/her personal shopping from Morrisons.

Comment: It was a hackney carriage:)

Answer (score 0):

Your case is strange, this usually does not happen with GPS.
It may jump 30m, sometimes 50m.
Either you have hit an extremely rare case, looking on thousands of devices, 
or there is a bug in the GPS chip you are using.

Or most probably you are using alternative location sources like Cell-Tower locations, which is known to have an accuracy of not better than 1km. Make sure that you use GPS Provider only.

Your log output of "NetworkLocation" makes me doubt that you are using GPS only.
If you are 100% sure that the location was delivered by GPS (It must have a valid speed, and a valid course, then it is from GPS, or you are able to read out which Provider delivered the location (GPS Provider or Network provider) then read further:

Once I have seen a 300km jump, which either was caused by a defect GPS satellite or a bug in GPS chip implementation.

What you can do is to filter out movements that could only be realized with unrealistic high vehicle speeds.

In your case it was "several kilometers" let assume it was 3.
That is 3000m in 80s = 37m /s = 135 km/h which is a realistic speed for vehicle on highways.
For a proper filtering you need to check the location every second, and look for unrealistic jumps.

Besides that there is no way to have a guarantee in GPS. All accuracies are estimations.
If an horizontal accuracy of 14m is estimated, you can never be sure if it is 50m or 2m from real location.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Google map distance between those two locations is 244KM which is unrealistic. As you mentioned in the reply, I already have a check in my code to ignore a location if the speed calculated(as you mentioned - using distance between previous and current location) is beyond 200KM/hour., but then since the device might not sometimes get a fix for longer duration, I am considering the new location directly if the previous location was more than 70 seconds older., - which exact is caused the problem in this case.!

Comment: Those two locations are provided by GPS provider for sure(Each time I collect location and log the locations provided by both as you can see in the log).

Comment: smartphones (for sure ios) also initially may deliver an old location from previous day. So always check the timestamp of the location to not deviate from the system time by more then some seconds.

Comment: The devices were on all the duration and did not restart for sure in the past 5 hours of the log timestamp. So, I don't think it has something to do with stale location data.

Comment: Maybe a bad device, it seems the error is hardware based.